# Google Maps Bar

Tags: search, maps

I am trying to simply add a Google Search bar onto my own map but am experiencing problems. I can't seem to get it to work! I've tried map.enableGoogleBar(); but that just gets rid of my KML layer and doesn't add a search box!

Here is the code:

```
 function initialize() {
        // set up startup options for the map 
        // disabled double click as it was annoying and streetview control removed. 
        var myOptions = {
            zoom: 10,
            //minZoom: 16,
            center: new google.maps.LatLng(50.45750, -3.84521),
            mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
            disableDoubleClickZoom: true,
            streetViewControl: false,

            mapTypeControl: true,
            navigationControl: true,
            navigationControlOptions: {
                style: google.maps.NavigationControlStyle.ZOOM_PAN,
                position: google.maps.ControlPosition.TOP_LEFT
            },
            scaleControl: true,
                scaleControlOptions: {
                position: google.maps.ControlPosition.BOTTOM_LEFT
            }

            enableGoogleBar: true,
            googleBarOptions: {showOnLoad:true},
        };

        // create the new map
        map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map_canvas'),
            myOptions);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's 2 issues I see

1. You're missing a comma before 'enableGoogleBar' in the myOptions object.
2. You're using Google Maps v3 API and checking the docs at  https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference it does not mention support for the enableGoogleBar option at all. It was only available in version 2 of the Google Maps API.

Comment: Ah thank you very much! I didn't realise that the Google bar function didn't carry over to API V3 :)